# Autohotkey WinMenuSelectItem and MSOffice Word Ribbon

Tags: microsoft-word, autohotkey, ribbon, ms-office-communicator

Is it possible to invoke the MS Office Word Ribbons with WinMenuSelectIem?

Or is there a way to manage the Office Ribbons via ahk?

Comment: Have you tried sending alt then the relevant sequence? Works for me

Comment: sorry I did not get your answer. what do you suggest?

Comment: Put it as a answer as too long for comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is use the keyboard shortcuts within the office ribbon (alt key sequence) to access the items within eg.

[image]

Access pattern:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>><kbd>H</kbd>><kbd>F</kbd>><kbd>I</kbd>><kbd>S</kbd>

Would be written in autohotkey as:

> ^!t::
>   send {alt}hfis 
>   return

So by using the key stroke sequence you would normally use you can access the content you need to

Comment: so I guess that the same procedure could be to anything in the ribbon